# MySQL - how can I find out what person two has but person one not

Tags: mysql, sql, compare

I have the following table:

```
-------------------------
| id | Person | Car     |
| 1  | 1      | BMW     |
| 2  | 1      | Ford    |
| 3  | 1      | VW      |
| 4  | 2      | BMW     |
| 5  | 2      | Mercedes|
| 6  | 2      | VMW     |
| 7  | 2      | FIAT    |
-------------------------
```

So here is my challenge:

I want to know which cars `Person 2` has got, that `Person 1` doesn't. Next, I want to add these cars to `Person 1` and after that, I need to delete Person 2.

Can someone tell me how the query has to look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a self left join of the table:

```
select t2.car
from tablename t2 left join tablename t1
on t1.person = 1 and t2.car = t1.car
where t2.person = 2 and t1.car is null;
```

So to insert the cars in the table (assuming that id is auto increment):

```
insert into tablename(person, car)
select 1, t2.car
from tablename t2 left join tablename t1
on t1.person = 1 and t2.car = t1.car
where t2.person = 2 and t1.car is null;
```

And then delete the rows of person 2:

```
delete from tablename where person = 2;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/czK4TC5FR1XWXzGGNCvtqc/0).

Comment: Can I run this in one query from my php script via PDO ?

Comment: You can't insert and delete in 1 query. You must run the 2 last queries separately.

Answer (score 1):

```
create temporary table tabletemp like table1;
insert into tabletemp (Select * from table1 where Person=2 and table1.car not in (select car from table1 where person=1));
insert into table1 (Select null,1,car from tabletemp);
drop temporary table tabletemp;
```

I assume that your table is called table1, and that your id column is an autoincrement column